# Solution for ODE $\dot{x}=F(x)$ with $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ smooth, periodic & positive.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, periodic & positive and $x(t)$ is a solution for $\dot{x}=F(x)$ and
$$T:=\int_{0}^{p}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy$$
then $x(t+T)-x(t)=p$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.
This exercise belong to Chicone, Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications. The hint is:

1. Define 
   $$G(x)=\int_{c}^{x}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy$$
   and show that $g(z)=G(z+p)-G(z)$ is constant

2.Proof that $G(x(b))-G(x(a))=b-a$ (I suppose that $a<b$)
The first I do the next:
$$G(z+p)-G(z)=\int_{c}^{z+p}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy-\int_{c}^{z}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy= \int_{z}^{z+p}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy=\int_{0}^{p}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy=T$$
The last equality since $F$ is periodic and positive.
For (2) I try to use $\dot{x}(t)=F(x(t))$ on the next way

$$G(x(b))-G(x(a))=\int_{c}^{x(b)}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy-\int_{c}^{x(a)}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy= \int_{x(a)}^{x(b)}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy$$
and the other and $$\frac{1}{F(y)}=\frac{1}{\dot{y}(s)}$$
Then 
$$\int_{x(a)}^{x(b)}\frac{1}{F(y)}dy=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\dot{y}(s)}dy$$
where $dy=\dot{y}(s)ds$ and therefore
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\dot{y}(s)}dy=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{\dot{y}(s)}\dot{y}(s)ds=\int_{a}^{b}ds=b-a$$
I don't know if this is the way.

But the next question is if $F$ change of sign and the problem is define $G$, exist problem with the integration limit and maybe $G$ is not well defined.

Comment: Well, if $F: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, then the solution of Cauchy problem is unique. And if $F(x)$ changes sign when passing through point $x^\ast$, then $x(t) \equiv x^\ast$ is a solution of ODE. No other trajectory can pass through this point (because of uniqueness), so limits of integration never could have $x^\ast$ as an interior point.

Comment: Thanks, my problem remains that still do not see how I get the equation $x(t+T)-x(t)=p$ of these two results.

Comment: Are you assuming that $p$ is a multiple of the period of $F$? Otherwise your last equality in the proof of part 1 does not hold...